# How can i display specific record using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

All

```
<ul class="icontacts">
    <li id="a" class="item" style="display: block; "><a name="a" class="title">A</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="my all">ajay</a>
                <a class="my all">anand</a>
                <a class="ex all">amy</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li id="c" class="item pmy" style="display: block; "><a name="c" class="title">C</a>
         <ul>
          <li>
              <a class="my all">Chim</a>
              <a class="my all">Ciny</a>
              <a class="ex all">Commy</a>
          </li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li id="d" class="item pmy" style="display: block; "><a name="d" class="title">D</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="my all">don</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

In above code i have list of entry shorted alphabetic wise.
now i have two type of entry one is "my" and another is "ex"

I have two button if i click on "My entry" it will display only "my" class entry with alphabetic li

```
<li id="a" class="item pmy" style="display: block; "><a name="c" class="title">C</a>
```

same for "ex" class button for other entry.

What i am doing is this but its fails if one li with class "item" have 2 different("my" and "ex")  entry.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".pall").css("display","none");
    });

    $(".all_click").click(function(){
       $(".all").css("display","block"); 
    });

    $(".my_click").click(function(){
       $(".all").css("display","none");
       $(".my").css("display","block"); 
    });

    $(".ex_click").click(function(){
       //ec click function

       $(".my").css("display","none"); 
       $(".ex").css("display","block"); 

    });
</script>
```

**Result i want is**

For All case:

```
A
ajay
anand
amy
B
Chim
Ciny
Commy
D
don
```

For case my

```
A
ajay
anand
B
Chim
Ciny
D
don
```

For case ex

```
A
amy
B
Commy
```

**In this case li with item class will also not display.**

Comment: If you want to hide/show elements you can also use `toggle()` http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ or `hide()` and `show()` which will save you a lot code and CSS problems.

Comment: put this in a demo on jsfiddle.net with enough css can see what you want. Your js hides a class `pall` not even shown in markup

Answer (score 1):

1. Put **everything** in the ready function
2. Use `hide()` and `show()`

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".pall").hide();

    $(".all_click").click(function() {
        $(".all").show();
    });

    $(".my_click").click(function() {
        $(".all").hide();
        $(".my").show();
    });

    $(".ex_click").click(function() {
        //ec click function
        $(".my").hide();
        $(".ex").show();

    });
});​
```

Comment: can you please check result what i want